# How Do I control other apps in ios, is it even possible?

Tags: ios

I am new to programing, have been programing in Swift for about 9 months now and I have experimented with a lot of stuff I want to know how to control other apps on a phone with my application if I can do it then explain or point me to a link that explains this topic well and how to do it.

Comment: What does "control" mean?

Comment: controle in the sense that i want to block quit and stop apps at times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open other apps with URL schemes. But it's not possible to "control" other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control other applications from your app.But at the same time you can open the app and **share** the data like message, image, link to other applications by the use of `UIActivityController`